# Minimum of the function involving square roots

Tags: analysis, derivatives, optimization

Let $x \in [0,b]$ where $b$ is positive. How to find minimum for the following function, defined on $[0,b]$:
$$F(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+s_1^2}}{v_1}+\frac{\sqrt{(b-x)^2+s_2^2}}{v_2}$$
Here $s_1,s_2,v_1,v_2,b$ are all positive constants. I came across this example while solving some physical problem.

Comment: Does this problem have to do with Fermat??

Comment: My motivation was the following physical problem: two person are located in the plane, one in the point $(0,0))$ and the other in the point $(b,s_1+s_2)$. The first person has to approach the second and moves with velocity $v_1$ in the strip $\{(x,y): 0 \leq y \leq s_1\}$ and in the strip  $\{(x,y): s_1 \leq y \leq s_1+s_2\}$ he moves with the velocity $v_2$. What the minimal time to reach this second guy?

Comment: @truebaran Hint: replace the people with light rays propagating in media with different diffraction indexes.

Comment: Yes, I see this analogy however I'm rather curious how to solve this _mathematical_ problem

Comment: Note that $F$ is convex. If $F$ has a stationary point, it is optimal. Otherwise, the optimum occurs at the boundary.

Comment: And how to find this optimal point? This leads to some unpleasant polynomial equation of degree 4.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937158/minimum-value-of-fracx-a2-p-frac-12v-1-frac-x-b2-q

Comment: Thank You, this answers my question.